# Installing NDK side by side is taking too long (expo modules core stuck)

Tags: react-native, npm, expo, node-modules, npm-install

[Link](https://docs.expo.dev/bare/installing-expo-modules/#manual-installation)I tried to install expo in react-native project. But the build stuck at expo-modules-core. It took like 10-20 minutes. and it was still stuck.

I installed through automatic installation and it gives me this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSn1T.png) 5 high severity vulnerabilities. Without npm audit fix, the build is stuck at expo-modules-core.

Comment: could you solve this problem?
I have the same issue

Comment: What is the problem? Is the build stuck?